# How does a smart contract get metadata from a non IPFS endpoint?

Tags: nft

I've been experimenting with NFTs for a while, but I cannot seem to understand how smart contracts get data from non IPFS, API endpoints.

See for example, this transaction:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xbb1d1c7e9cc132f4227af7ce2d45d4007347ca91bd7f6ba6acf506d14a164fec

Set's up as baseURI this endpoint:

https://meta.rebelkidsparade.com/meta/

When I request that endpoint, I get a 404 error, why is this? Is there something I'm missing? How did the contract get the NFT metadata?

Answer (score 1):

The base URI is common for all tokens. To get a certain token's metadata, the contract appends the `tokenId` to the baseURI before returning it.
See [this implementation from OZ](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/83644fdb6a9f75a652d2fe2d96cb26073a14f6f8/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L92) of the concerned function.

In your case check out the URL https://meta.rebelkidsparade.com/meta/1